# Lyrics required

Tags: listening

I bumped into [this video](https://www.facebook.com/EtaAureaTrashTelevisivoItaliano/videos/394269790781469/?fref=nf) on Facebook. [Here](http://www.gazzetta.it/Sportlife/Tempo-Libero/27-05-2015/toto-cutugno-che-canta-italiano-ma-cinese-via-paolo-sarpi-video-1101000094193.shtml) is the same video outside Facebook so everyone can see it. It is an Italian song, "L'Italiano" (The Italian man), sung in a Chinese version by an Italian singer, with what is like the worst pronunciation I ever heard for Chinese. The subs read:

> Let me sing
> Because I'm proud of it
> I'm Chinese
> A true Italiano.
>
> Good morning Italia gli spaghetti al dente
> And a partisan for president
> with the car radio always in the right hand
> And a canary on the window
> Good Morning Italy with all you artists
> With too much America on the manifests
> With the songs, with love, with the heart
> With more women and fewer and fewer nuns
> Good morning Italia, good morning Maria
> With eyes full of melancholy
> Good morning God
> You know I'm here too
>
> Let me sing with the guitar in hand
> Let me sing a song slowly slowly
> Let me sing because I'm proud of it
> I'm a Chinese person, a true Italiano
>
> La la la …
>
> Let me sing with the guitar in hand
> Let me sing a song slowly slowly
> Let me sing because I'm proud of it
> I'm a chinese person, a true italian
>
> Let me sing
> Because I'm proud of it
> I'm a chinese person
> A true Italiano

I left the bits that are sung in Italian as they were in Italian. If anyone is willing to turn this code block into a block quote while keeping the linebreaks in place *and* avoiding huge line spacings, they are very welcome to do so. I did not manage that. I shared this video on Facebook saying:

> His pronunciation is simply AWFUL :).
> [Tag to a Chinese friend] 你明白他唱着什么吗？

My friend answered:

> 我只听懂几句：我感到自豪，我是中国人。这真的Italiano？对吗？

With that help, here is what I have figured out:

> 让我发现唱歌吧
> 因为我感到自豪
> 我是中国人
> 这真的Italiano。
>
> 早安Italia, gli spaghetti al dente.
> 一个？？有一个真相总统
> []
> []
> 早安Italia？？？书家们
> []
> []
> []
> 早安Italia，早安Maria
> []
> 早安神父
> 你知道我也存在
>
> 啦啦啦…
>
> 让我发现唱歌吧    ［］
> 让我发现唱一首过慢？？的歌曲
> 让我发现唱歌吧    因为我感到自豪
> 我是中国人    却真的Italiano
>
> 让我发现唱歌吧
> 因为我感到自豪
> 我是中国人
> 却真的Italiano

Some remarks:

1. That fāxiàn sounds terribly out of place, so what does it mean? Is it correct?
2. That Italiano line is uncertain. zhēn de is pretty certain, but is it shì? zhè? què? Something else?
3. Shūjiāmen is absolutely uncertain, half invented in fact. Is it right?
4. The last two full lines are uncertain, because in the end I did not re-listen to the second one because I was convinced I wouldn't gain anything that way. Are they correct?
5. Is the guòmàn right? What are the two missing characters?
6. Obviously lots of pieces are empty because I could only guess a few syllables here and there.

So I tried googling the lyrics, but all I could find were the Italian lyrics and possibly an English translation, but I want to know what he is singing in Chinese. Can anybody help? Thx.

**Update**

After the last answer reminded me of this, I tried to transcribe the sounds I heard in a very rough Pinyin, and got:

> Rang wo faxian chang ge ba 
> Yin we wo gan dao zi hao 
> Wo shi zong guo ren 
> Qie zhen de Italiano 
>
> Zao wan Italia gli spaghetti al dente 
> Yi ge yang guo you yi ge yan xiang zhong tong 
> You shou jiu xian na zhe yi su qi shen yi shang 
> Bi shen dian gu dan chang zai chuang kou shang 
> Zao wan Italia gen ni yi su jia men 
> Gen hai ma tai guo mei guo lai de si wen 
> Gen ge qu, gen yi xin, gan ai xing 
> Lo me nu yu wei lai wei shao siu nu 
> Zao wan Italia, zao wan Maria 
> Ni de shen chong man you chou de yan shen 
> Zao wan shen fu 
> Ni zhi dao wo gen cun zai 
>
> Rang wo fa xian chang ge ba 
> Na zhe zhi kui ta zi ta 
> Rang wo fa xian gan chang yi shou wan man ting liu de ge qu 
> Rang wo fa xian chang ge ba 
> Yin wei wo gan dao zi hao 
> Wo shi zong guo ren 
> Qie zhen de Italiano 
>
> La la la 
>
> Rang wo fa xian chang ge ba 
> Na zhe zhi kui ta zi ta 
> Rang wo fa xian gan chang yi shou wan man ting liu de ge qu 
> Rang wo fa xian chang ge ba 
> Yin wei wo gan dao zi hao 
> Wo shi zong guo ren 
> Qie zhen de Italiano

With that, I tried filling some holes, and got:

> 让我发现唱歌吧 
> 因为我感到自豪 
> 我是中国人 
> 这真的Italiano。 
>
> 早安Italia, gli spaghetti al dente. 
> 一个 yang guo 有一个真相总统 
> 右手就先拿着一 su qi shen yi shang 
> Bi shen dian 孤单唱在窗口上 
> 早安Italia跟你艺术家们 
> 跟还嘛太过美国来的斯文 
> 跟歌曲，跟你心，跟爱情 
> Lo 美女有越来越少修女 
> 早安Italia，早安Maria 
> 你的深充满忧愁的眼神 
> 早安神父 
> 你知道我也存在 
>
> 啦啦啦… 
>
> 让我发现唱歌吧 拿着 zhi kui ta 自弹 
> 让我发现敢唱一首 wan 慢 ting liu 的歌曲 
> 让我发现唱歌吧 因为我感到自豪 
> 我是中国人 却真的Italiano 
>
> 让我发现唱歌吧 
> 因为我感到自豪 
> 我是中国人 
> 却真的Italiano

Perhaps the "que zhen de Italiano" are "shi zhen de Italiano", as suggested in comments, but it really sounds like a "que" or "qie". Also, I think "jiu xian" should be "zǒngshì" (总是, always). And, those "gen"'s (gen gequ gen ni xin gen aiqing) really sound like "ka". Perhaps "Lo" = "duō" (多). "wan man" = 慢慢, "ting liu" = 停留, though it sounds out of place. Any help in finishing this?

**Update:**

I posted on Facebook asking all my Chinese friends for help, and one suggested 发现 should be 放声.

**Update 2**

After relistening and doing some more Wiktionary search, here is what I think I have:

> 让我放声唱歌吧
> 因为我感到自豪
> 我是中国人
> 却真的Italiano。
>
> 早安Italia, gli spaghetti al dente.
> 一个 ya guo 游击队员像总统
> 右手总是拿着一 su qi shen yi shang
> ⸢Bi she niao⸥(金丝鸟?) 孤单唱在窗口上
> 早安Italia跟你艺术家们
> 跟还 ma 太多美国来的斯文
> 跟歌曲，跟爱心，跟内心
> ⸢Lo me⸥(多么?) 女（又？）越来越少修女
> 早安Italia，早安Maria
> 你的深充满忧愁的眼神
> 早安神父
> 你知道我也存在
>
> 让我放声唱歌吧
> 拿着只贵的吉他
> 让我放声敢唱
> 一首过慢平语的歌曲
> 让我放声唱歌吧
> 因为我感到自豪
> 我是中国人
> 却真的Italiano
>
> 啦啦啦啦啦啦啦
> 啦啦啦啦啦啦啦
> 啦啦啦啦啦
> 啦啦啦啦啦
> 啦啦啦啦啦
> 啦啦啦啦啦
> 啦啦啦啦啦啦啦
> 啦啦啦啦啦啦啦
> 啦啦啦啦啦
> 啦啦啦啦啦
> 啦啦啦啦啦
> 啦啦啦啦啦
>
> 让我放声唱歌吧
> 拿着只贵的吉他
> 让我放声敢唱
> 一首过慢平语的歌曲
> 让我放声唱歌吧
> 因为我感到自豪
> 我是中国人
> 却真的Italiano
>
> 让我放声唱歌吧
> 因为我感到自豪
> 我是中国人
> 却真的Italiano

**Update 3**

Could that be 跟还嘛太多美国来的斯文?

**Update 4**

I guess "qi shen yi shang" is 汽车音箱, another bad translation because "autoradio" is not just the speakers as this would make it mean in Chinese. We are left with figuring out the classifier which sounds like "su" that the lyrics are using here.

**Update 5**

The classifier is probably 副, making the line 右手总是拿着一副汽车音箱.

**Update 6**

The Italiano line might be 就真的Italiano or 真正的Italiano. Jiù seems out of place, and his lips don't seem to close to a /u/ (jiù would be read by him as joo), and the clear j-sound excludes shì and què, and zhè feels strange, so I'm going for 真正.

Comment: Some other stuff i heard:
1. 早安Italia？？？书家们 is actually 早安Italia艺术家们
2. The line before that is ????窗户上
3. I think all the Italiano lines are "是真的Italiano" and it's consistent throughout the song as the italian subs are the same throughout, so I doubt they'd change the Chinese line.

Comment: More like 早安Italia跟你艺术家们 I'd say.

Comment: Probably 孤单唱在窗户上啊, at least I seemed to hear that 孤单唱在 around there and due to the tune the stress should be on the next-to-last syllable, hence the 啊.

Comment: ???太多美国??… right after yishujiamen.

Comment: 跟歌曲，跟你心，？？？？ (with your songs with love with the heart)

Comment: kind of guessed it would be a @MickG question from the title.

Comment: And you were damn right @user3306356 :).

Comment: 拿着 zhi kui ta 自弹= 拿着只吉他自弹?

Comment: @FanZheng Actually I think it's 拿着只贵的吉他, with "jita" being read "zida" Anyway I made my own Chinese version which I will post on May 7 on [my blog](https://michelegorini.blogspot.com) along with what I got out of this one. If I had to guess, he's somehow reading ji as z + the i of ji, and whoever's doing the backup grossly misunderstood that and thought it was an actual zi, Or I'm just hearing the (non-)vowel of zi in there because of whatever unknown thing in the recording screwing up my perception. He definitely sings an ee-sound, not the uh-like sound of zi.

Answer (score 2):

There is a very popular Finnish version of this song by Kari Tappio which has been performed together with Toto Cutugno as a bilingual duet. The melody is also popularized in Português, Hebrew, Arabic, Hindi, Vietnamese and several other languages apart from the above mentioned Chinese performed by Toto himself.

I'm working on setting some globalist peacenik lyrics for it to perform at our family Christmas dinner this year

Comment: [Here it is](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9nTAVjr0zZ4) :). Also, there's a Russian song which "stole" the tune and was also performed as a duet, but the lyrics have nothing to do with Italy or Russia: [this thing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=77HuVmuZ22k).

Comment: [Portuguese](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AFv00cqAqQk) and [Arabic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q4xL1nc6PNQ). And [Hindi](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r0VqHnUvohw) and [Vietnamese](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SSszeIGD6I8). Couldn't find Hebrew.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my blog post about the song: [L'italiano](https://michelegorini.blogspot.com/2019/05/litaliano.html). The lyrics I concluded for this version:

让我放声唱歌吧
因为我感到自豪
我是中国人
就真的Italiano。

早安Italia, gli spaghetti al dente.
一个爱国(?)遊击队员像总统
右手总是拿着一副汽车音箱
金丝鸟(?)孤单唱在窗口上
早安Italia跟你艺术家们
跟还嘛(?)太多美国来的檄文 (perh. 跟那么太多?)
跟歌曲，跟爱情，跟内心
跟(?)多美女(?)又越来越少修女
早安Italia，早安Maria
你的深充满忧愁的眼神
早安神父
你知道我也存在

让我放声唱歌吧
拿着只贵的吉他
让我放声敢唱
一首过慢平语的歌曲
让我放声唱歌吧
因为我感到自豪
我是中国人
就真的Italiano

啦啦啦啦啦啦啦
啦啦啦啦啦啦啦
啦啦啦啦啦
啦啦啦啦啦
啦啦啦啦啦
啦啦啦啦啦
啦啦啦啦啦啦啦
啦啦啦啦啦啦啦
啦啦啦啦啦
啦啦啦啦啦
啦啦啦啦啦
啦啦啦啦啦

让我放声唱歌吧
拿着只贵的吉他
让我放声敢唱
一首过慢平语的歌曲
让我放声唱歌吧
因为我感到自豪
我是中国人
就真的Italiano

让我放声唱歌吧
因为我感到自豪
我是中国人
就真的Italiano

Answer (score 0):

*After my rough translation, i don't think the lyrics makes any sense at all, in particular the little observation in Italy described in paragraph 2.

Let me sing
(让我唱歌吧)
Because I'm proud of it
(因为我感到自豪)
I'm Chinese
(我是中国人)
A true Italiano.
(一個真的意大利人)

Good morning Italia gli spaghetti al dente
(早安呀意大利面条)
And a partisan for president
(还有属于总统的党派)
with the car radio always in the right hand
(汽车收音机永远在右手)
And a canary on the window
(还有在窗上的一只金丝雀)
Good Morning Italy with all you artists
(早安呀意大利和妳所有的艺术家)
With too much America on the manifests
(和妳所有过多的美國旅客)
With the songs, with love, with the heart
(和妳的歌 妳的爱 妳的心)
With more women and fewer and fewer nuns
(和妳越來越多的女人 越來越少的修女)
Good morning Italia, good morning Maria
(早安呀意大利 早安呀玛利亚)
With eyes full of melancholy
(你那忧郁的眼神)
Good morning God
(早安呀神)
You know I'm here too
(你知道我也在与你同在)

Let me sing with the guitar in hand
(让我以手中的结他伴唱)
Let me sing a song slowly slowly
(讓我慢慢地唱)
Let me sing because I'm proud of it
(让我唱 因为我感到自豪)
I'm a Chinese person, a true Italiano
(我是一个中国人 一個真的意大利人)
La la la …

Let me sing with the guitar in hand
Let me sing a song slowly slowly
Let me sing because I'm proud of it
I'm a chinese person, a true italian

Let me sing
Because I'm proud of it
I'm a chinese person
A true Italiano